# How do I get all the rows in the table with MAX value for a COUNT of the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

| dept_id | course_id | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CS | 101 | 11 |
| Math | 101 | 11 |
| CS | 101 | 12 |
| CS | 201 | 22 |
| Math | 301 | 22 |
| EE | 102 | 33 |
| Math | 201 | 33 |

This is the current sql table called "enrolled" and
I need to select all the departments with the highest number of enrolments.

I tried

```
SELECT dept_id,COUNT(dept_id) as "enrollments" 
FROM enrolled 
GROUP BY dept_id;
```

to get the number of enrollments for each department. But then I am unsure on how to get all the departments with the maximum enrollment.

The final result should be a single column with "CS" and "Math".

Comment: You really should take your time and explain your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `DENSE_RANK` function to give a rank for each department according to the count of enrolled students as the following:

```
SELECT dept_id
FROM
(
  SELECT dept_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM enrolled
  GROUP BY dept_id
) T
WHERE rnk=1
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ApnqwqVu).

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING COUNT clause if you have older MySQL version which doesn't support windows functions

```
select dept_id 
from  enrolled 
group by dept_id
having count(dept_id) =  ( select max(tot_count) 
                           from ( select count(dept_id) as tot_count 
                                  from  enrolled 
                                  group by dept_id
                                 ) tbl
                          );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/sNcMzVxe

The following query will return the max count which is then used in the having clause

```
  select max(tot_count) 
  from ( select count(dept_id) as tot_count 
         from  enrolled 
         group by dept_id
        ) tbl
```

In simple words in your case it will be `having count(dept_id) = 3;`

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to calculate the total score based on each department, which we did in CTE 1 using `GROUP BY`
- then you need to create a rank based on the highest score (descending order), if the scores can be tied you need to create a rank based on `DENSE_RANK()`. This would always generate the same rank for the same values, in your case it is looking at the total_scores from the the step 1, in the highest oder (`ORDER BY` is set to `desc`). If you want to do the query other way around you can remove `DESC` and the window function will by default work in `ASC` order
- In the last you filter on the rank = 1 using `where` clause to get the highest enrolled departments

```
with main as (
  select dept_id, count(student_id) as total_enrolled_students
  from enrolled
  group by 1
  ),ranking as (
  select *, 
  dense_rank() over(order by total_enrolled_students desc) as rank_
  from main
  )
select * from ranking where rank_ = 1;
```